# Getting asymptotic behaviour of an integral?

Tags: asymptotics

I am interested in the $\rho\sim0$ asymptotics of the following expression
$$
\int_{1.1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k\rho)}{k^{1.9}\rho}\frac{1}{\log\frac{1}{k}}\,dk
$$
any ideas of how to tackle this?

Comment: Have you tried to cut the tail of the integral (say, from 10000) and after that to replace $\sin (k\rho)=k\rho-\frac{k^3\rho^3} 6 +O((k\rho)^5)?$

Comment: @user64494: This does not work. if we let $\rho\to 0$ under the integral, the resulting integral diverges!

Comment: @Michael Renardy : Could you elaborate and base your statement?

Answer (score 3):

the small-$\rho$ asymptotics of
$$I(\rho)=-\int_{1.1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k\rho)}{\rho k^{1.9}\ln k}\,dk$$

is governed by the large-$k$ behavior of the integrand, which gives $I(\rho)\propto \rho^{1.9-2}$ up to a logarithmic factor, and a numerical evaluation supports the asymptotic

$$I_{\rm asymp}(\rho)=-\rho^{-0.1}(3.5+0.126\ln\rho)$$

[image]

Log-linear plot of $-\rho^{0.1}I(\rho)$ (blue line) and $-\rho^{0.1}I_{\rm asymp}(\rho)$ (orange line)

---

UPDATE, following Bazin's recent answer:

I have some convergence issues with a numerical evaluation at much smaller $\rho$, but if I can trust the Mathematica output the curve does seem to level off towards an asymptote at zero, as derived by Bazin, possibly as $I(\rho)=-\text{constant}\times(\rho^{0.1}\log\rho)^{-1}$.

[image]

Comment: Can you present these numerics (possibly, through Dropbox)?

Comment: @user64494 --- added a plot in support of the asymptotics

Comment: @CarloBeenakker any analytic argument leading to this behavior?

Comment: That's nice.  A change of variable $x = \rho k$ converts the integral to a tractable looking integrable that I think gives the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Setting $t=\rho k$ the integral in question becomes
$$
\int_{1.1\rho}^\infty\frac{\sin t}{\rho^{0.1}t^{1.9}\log (t/\rho)}\;dt.
$$
Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then for $\rho\rightarrow 0$ we have
$$
\int_{1.1\rho}^{\rho^{1/2}} \frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}\log (t/\rho)}\;dt \ll \int_{1.1\rho}^{\rho^{1/2}} \frac{1}{t^{0.9}}\;dt \ll \rho^{1/20},
$$
$$
\int_{\rho^{1/2}}^\epsilon\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}\log (t/\rho)}\;dt \ll\frac{1}{\log\rho^{-1}}\int_{\rho^{1/2}}^\epsilon\frac{dt}{t^{0.9}}\ll\frac{\epsilon^{0.1}}{\log\rho^{-1}},
$$
and
$$
\left|\int_{\epsilon^{-1}}^\infty\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}\log (t/\rho)}\;dt\right| \ll
\int_{\epsilon^{-1}}^\infty\frac{1}{t^{1.9}\log \rho^{-1}}\;dt \ll\frac{\epsilon^{0.1}}{\log\rho^{-1}}.
$$
Hence for $\rho<\epsilon^2$ the integral in question equals
$$
\rho^{-0.1}\int_\epsilon^{\epsilon^{-1}}\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}\log(t/\rho)}\;dt + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\epsilon^{0.1}\rho^{-0.1}}{\log\rho^{-1}}\right).
$$
Now
$$
\int_\epsilon^{\epsilon^{-1}}\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}\log(t/\rho)}\;dt = \int_\epsilon^{\epsilon^{-1}}\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}(\log\rho^{-1} + \mathcal{O}(\log\epsilon^{-1}))}\;dt,
$$
since in the range of integration we have $|\log t|\leq\log\epsilon^{-1}$. Putting $L=\log\rho^{-1}$ and $\alpha=\log\epsilon^{-1}$ we have for $\alpha<L/2$, i.e. $\rho<\epsilon^2$
$$
\left|\frac{1}{L}-\frac{1}{L+\alpha}\right| = \frac{|\alpha|}{L(L+\alpha)} \ll \frac{|\alpha|}{L^2},
$$
thus
\begin{split}
\int_\epsilon^{\epsilon^{-1}}\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}(L + \mathcal{O}(\alpha))}\;dt &= \int_\epsilon^{\epsilon^{-1}}\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}}\left(\frac{1}{L}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\alpha}{L^2}\right)\right)\;dt\\
& = \frac{1}{L}\int_\epsilon^{\epsilon^{-1}}\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}}\;dt + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\alpha}{L^2}\int_\epsilon^{\epsilon^{-1}}\frac{|\sin t|}{t^{1.9}}\right).
\end{split}
In the error term we bound $|\sin t|$ by $\min(t, 1)$ and split the integral into the range $[\epsilon, 1]$ and $[1, \epsilon^{-1}]$. Doing so we find that the integral converges, hence the error term is $\mathcal{O}(\frac{\alpha}{L^2})$. In the main term we extend the integral to the range $(0,\infty)$. Doing so introduces an error
$$
\frac{1}{L}\int_0^\epsilon\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}}\;dt \leq \frac{1}{L}\int_0^\epsilon\frac{1}{t^{0.9}}\;dt\ll\frac{\epsilon^{0.1}}{L}
$$
and another one of size
$$
\frac{1}{L}\int_{\epsilon^{-1}}^\infty\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}}\;dt \leq \frac{1}{L}\int_{\epsilon^{-1}}^\infty\frac{dt}{t^{1.9}} \ll \frac{\epsilon^{0.9}}{L}.
$$
Together we obtain
$$
\int_\epsilon^{\epsilon^{-1}}\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}\log(t/\rho)}\;dt =
\frac{1}{L}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}}\;dt + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\epsilon^{0.1}}{L}+\frac{\alpha}{L^2}\right).
$$
Together with the bounds obtained before we get that the original integral equals 
$$
\frac{\rho^{-0.1}}{L}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}}\;dt + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\rho^{-0.1}\epsilon^{0.1}}{L}+\frac{\rho^{-0.1}\alpha}{L^2}\right).
$$
Putting $\epsilon=L^{10}$, i.e. $\alpha=10\log\log\rho^{-1}$, we get
$$
\frac{\rho^{-0.1}}{L}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}}\;dt + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\rho^{-0.1}\log\log\rho^{-1}}{(\log\rho^{-1})^2}\right).
$$
The integral in the main term is positive, thus the main term is larger than the error term by a factor $\frac{\log\log\rho^{-1}}{\log\rho^{-1}}$, and we got an asymptotic formula.

The main source of error is the approximation of the term $\log\rho^{-1}+t$ by $\log\rho^{-1}$. If you need better asymptotics, you would have to use the series expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x}$. In this way you would get an asymptotic series in $\frac{1}{L}$, but the computations would become rather long.

Comment: How do you justify $\int_{\epsilon}^{\epsilon^{-1}}\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}\log\frac{t}{\rho}}dt=\int_{\epsilon}^{\epsilon^{-1}}\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}[\log\rho^{-1}+\mathcal{O}(\log\epsilon^{-1})]}dt$?

Comment: We have $\epsilon\leq t\leq\epsilon^{-1}$, thus $\log(t/\rho)=\log\rho^{-1}+\log t=\log\rho^{-1}+\mathcal{O}(\log\epsilon^{-1})$.

Comment: Good thanks. Now, how do you justify $\int_{\epsilon}^{\epsilon^{-1}}\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}[\log\rho^{-1}+\mathcal{O}(\log\epsilon^{-1})]}dt=\frac{1}{\log\rho^{-1}}\int_{\epsilon}^{\epsilon^{-1}}\frac{\sin t}{t^{1.9}}dt+\mathcal{O}\bigg(\frac{\log\epsilon^{-1}}{\log^2\rho^{-1}}\int_{\epsilon}^{\epsilon^{-1}}\frac{|\sin t|}{t^{1.9}}dt\bigg)$?

Comment: I don't wanna annoy you but everything that goes beyond where you say "Now ..." puzzles me. My knowledge of asymptotic analysis is very elementary and I would appreciate more indications

Comment: I expanded the computations, stretching the performance of MathJax to the limits of my computer.

Comment: Much appreciated, I will have a thorough look

Comment: I have given the bounty because this looks to be alright, although for various reasons I haven't resolved all the details, what I am saying is, I may have more questions still ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let us define $\epsilon_0=0.1$, so that
$
I(x)=- x^{-1}\Im\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{H(t-1-\epsilon_0)e^{itx}}{t^{2-\epsilon_0}\ln t} dt.
$
We get for $x>0$,
$$
I(x)=-x^{-1}\int_{x(1+\epsilon_0)}^{+\infty} \tau^{-2+\epsilon_0}x^{2-\epsilon_0}\frac{\sin{\tau}}{\ln \tau-\ln x}x^{-1}d\tau=-
x^{-\epsilon_0}\int_{x(1+\epsilon_0)}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin \tau}{\tau^{2-\epsilon_0}}\frac{d\tau}{\ln \tau-\ln x}.
$$
We note that 
$
\ln \tau-\ln x\ge \ln (1+\epsilon_0)=\epsilon_1>0.
$
On the other hand the function
$$
\tau\mapsto \frac{\sin \tau}{\tau^{2-\epsilon_0}}\quad \text{belongs to $L^1(\mathbb R_+)$},
$$
so that the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem gives
$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0_+}I(x)x^{\epsilon_0}=0.
$
Defining
$$
I_1(x)=-x^{-\epsilon_0}\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin \tau}{\tau^{2-\epsilon_0}}\frac{d\tau}{\ln \tau-\ln x},
$$
and noticing that $\ln \tau-\ln x\ge \ln(1/x)$ for $\tau \ge 1$, the same argument as above gives
$$
I_1(x)\sim_{x\rightarrow 0_+} -\frac{1}{x^{\epsilon_0}\ln (1/x)}
\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin \tau}{\tau^{2-\epsilon_0}}d\tau.
$$
We set
$
I_0(x)=
-
x^{-\epsilon_0}\int_{x(1+\epsilon_0)}^{1} \frac{\sin \tau}{\tau^{2-\epsilon_0}}\frac{d\tau}{\ln \tau-\ln x}.
$
We know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0_+} I_0(x) x^{\epsilon_0}=0$ and it remains to find an equivalent for $I_0(x)$ for $x\rightarrow 0_+$.

Comment: I extended the numerics, in support of your conclusion, thanks.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I completed my answer, but left a question for a remaining integral.

Answer (score 0):

Split the integral at $k \approx 1/\rho$. For $k \leq 1/\rho$ approximate $\sin(k \rho) \approx k \rho$ by it's Taylor expansion (just the first term suffices) and compute what you get, this is your *main term* . In the region $k \geq 1 / \rho$ make a linear change of variable $k \rho \rightarrow k$ and notice that this part of the integral vanishes as $\rho$ goes to zero, this is your *error term* .

Comment: I don't see how the second part vanishes when $\rho\to 0$, actually I think it is not the case

Comment: yes you're right i was too careless when making my change of variable, the other part contributes about an equal amount.